# cmake doesn't see struct header

Tags: cmake

I have project on C++ that contains h and cpp files. I used to build a project in Netbeans IDE, it has own Makefile, then i decided to build project with cmake. I left only the source code. I also have external include directories in /home/data/lib

Project tree:

```
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── devices
│   ├── RK.cpp
│   └── RK.h
├── LogWriter
│   ├── LogWriter.cpp
│   └── LogWriter.h
├── main.cpp
└── structs
    └── RK_structs.h
```

I created CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
project(wise_RK)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(SOURCES main.cpp)

include_directories(
    structs
    devices
    LogWriter
    /home/data/lib/wise_versioning
    /home/data/lib/wisenet
    /home/data/lib/wise_log
    /home/data/lib/wise_rs_device
    /home/data/lib/json
)

add_executable(wise_rk ${SOURCES})
add_definitions(-DSOME_IMPORTANT_DEFINITION)
```

Then i did this:

```
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake ..

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/anzipex/Downloads/wise_RK/build
```

Then i did make:

```
make
```

Results:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/wise_rk.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /home/awise/Downloads/wise_RK/main.cpp:15:0:
/home/awise/Downloads/wise_RK/devices/RK.h:16:32: fatal error: structs/RK_structs.h: No such file or directory
 #include "structs/RK_structs.h"
                                ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/wise_rk.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/wise_rk.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Seems like ../structs/RK_structs.h is working, but how to leave everything unchanged in the code?

Comment: Add `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` to `include_directories` arguments to fix the error. But if you want to add more sources in future you may want to learn some modern CMake depedency management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you say `include_directories(structs)` in CMake, that translates more or less directly to the `-Istructs` flag to your compiler.

So `#include "RK_structs.h"` will work with your current CMake file.

If you want to be able to `#include "structs/RK_structs.h"`, you need to make your *source* directory an include directory.
You can do it explicitly by stating

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

or implicitly by enabling the `CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR` flag as follows:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
```